# How to create a mindmap in Latex with hexagonal shapes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm busting my head on creating a mindmap in LaTex/TikZ with nodes being displayed not as boxes, circles or ellipses. Is there a way to create a mindmap using hexagons as children? The children ought to be connected to the corners. Parents and children should contain a short text

I've tried using the shapes package.

Thank you in advance, Pjotr

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)   With the `shapes.geometric` library, you can easily create regular hexagons (Example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw=black] (hexagon) at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`)  If this does not help you, please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you create mind maps and probably also add a setch of the desired output.

Comment: It may not be too trivial to make the connecting bars consistent with hexagons. Therefore, it is even more important that you show what you tried.

Comment: A massive thank you to you leandriis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first step is to change, as suggested by leandris, the nodes to hexagons. But then one is not really done.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{hexagon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[concept/.append style={hexagon},
  root concept/.append style={concept color=blue,minimum size=1.2cm,
  %outer sep=-1em,
  font=\sffamily\huge},
  level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60,font=\sffamily\large,
  %outer sep=-0.5em,
  level distance=17em},mindmap]
\node [concept] (n1) {Hello}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=red] {node[concept] (c1) {A}}
    child[concept color=orange] {node[concept] (c2) {B}}
    child[concept color=green!60!black] {node[concept] (c3) {C}}
    child[concept color=brown] {node[concept] (c4) {D}}
    child[concept color=yellow] {node[concept] (c5) {E}}
    child[concept color=purple] {node[concept] (c6) {F}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the connections are screwed up. A simple way to rectify this is to give the nodes some appropriate outer sep.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{hexagon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[concept/.append style={hexagon},
  root concept/.append style={concept color=blue,minimum size=1.2cm,
  outer sep=-1em,
  font=\sffamily\huge},
  level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60,font=\sffamily\large,
  outer sep=-0.5em,
  level distance=17em},mindmap]
\node [concept] (n1) {Hello}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=red] {node[concept] (c1) {A}}
    child[concept color=orange] {node[concept] (c2) {B}}
    child[concept color=green!60!black] {node[concept] (c3) {C}}
    child[concept color=brown] {node[concept] (c4) {D}}
    child[concept color=yellow] {node[concept] (c5) {E}}
    child[concept color=purple] {node[concept] (c6) {F}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As usual in the mind map business, the result is somewhat viewer dependent. The depicted output is the one you get with Acrobat Reader.

**ADDENDUM**: After seeing [this cool answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58681068/11685757) I reread the question. You only want to have the outer nodes as hexagons. Very well.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{hexagon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[root concept/.append style={concept color=blue,minimum size=1.2cm,
  font=\sffamily\huge},
  level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60,font=\sffamily\large,
  outer sep=-0.5em,concept/.append style={hexagon},
  level distance=14em},mindmap]
\node [concept] (n1) {Hello}
    [clockwise from=0,]
    child[concept color=red] {node[concept] (c1) {A}}
    child[concept color=orange] {node[concept] (c2) {B}}
    child[concept color=green!60!black] {node[concept] (c3) {C}}
    child[concept color=brown] {node[concept] (c4) {D}}
    child[concept color=yellow] {node[concept] (c5) {E}}
    child[concept color=purple] {node[concept] (c6) {F}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A massive thank you to you Schröedinger's cat! Leandriis and you saved my life!